# javamail access to a shared mailbox

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to write an java application that will access a additional, *shared* mailbox to read emails and perform other activities. I have no problem reading my own INBOX (or its folders & contents) but am having great difficulty finding information on how to access (and ultimately parse/read) a shared mailbox.

Comment: which mail protocol are you using?

Comment: If you are talking about shared mailboxes on Exchange, you may find that JavaMail/IMAP aren't going to be much help.  You probably need to look into using some .NET libraries that deal with Exchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help from the other answers, I figured out following solution, that works for com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "LOGIN");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@xyz.com\\shared_account_alias", "user_password");
```

With javax.mail:mail:1.4.7 following code works:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@xyz.com\\shared_account_alias", "user_password");
```

shared_account_alias is NOT the email address.

Eventually  I have found a more standard way of accessing the shared mailbox:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.sasl.enable", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.imaps.sasl.authorizationid", "shared_account_alias");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@xyz.com", "user_password");
```

Comment: The last way with `props.setProperty("mail.imaps.sasl.authorizationid", "shared_account_alias@xyz.com");` works for me.

Comment: For me `props.setProperty("mail.imap.sasl.authorizationid", "shared_account_alias")` and `props.setProperty( "mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true" )` did work with WildFly 25.0.0 and `jakarta.mail-1.6.7` (using STARTTLS).

Answer (score 5):

I am doing the following and it is working fine for me

```
properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("HOST", PORT, "DOMAIN\\USER\\SHAREDACCOUNT","pwd");
```

Here
DOMAIN\\USER\\SHAREDACCOUNT would be like this
suppose email account is tarun@abc.com then
abc\\tarun\\shared_MB

You also have to enter the password of tarun@abc.com account.

Answer (score 3):

The solution given by Tarun works. But an important note use the alias of the shared account and not the actual email address of shared account. 
So the actual format is: 
store.connect(DOMAIN, "USER@xyz.com\SHARED_ACCOUNT_ALIAS","USER_PASSWORD");