# How to use Javamail for accessing additional mailboxes (IMAP, Exchange 2010)

Tags: jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I want to access a shared mailbox (NOT FOLDER) via Javamail API (1.4.5) using IMAP(s) with plain logon. The mailserver is a Exchange Server 2010.

User: user1 (user1@domain.com)
pwd: xxxx

shared mailbox: shared_MB@domain.com

I´ve managed to get access to the user1 - mailbox:

```
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new ExchangeAuthenticator(username, password));
        session.setDebug(true);

        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");

        store.connect(imapHost, username, password);
```

properties:

mail.imaps.socketFactory.port = 993

mail.imaps.starttls.enable = true

mail.imaps.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback = false

username = user1@domain.com

password = xxxx

--> this works just fine! But now i want to access the additional mailbox by changing the login-String:

username=user1@domain.com/shared_MB

--> unfortunately I´m getting an "NO AUTHENTICATE" message:

```
   DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE PLAIN command result: A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

I was able to get access with Thunderbird, so I think there is something missing in my code...

Comment: Possible Duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951184/javamail-access-to-a-shared-mailbox/32634294#32634294. This solution works for me!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am doing the following and it is working fine for me

```java
properties = System.getProperties();
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("HOST", PORT, "DOMAIN\\USER\\SHAREDACCOUNT","pwd");
```

Here
DOMAIN\\USER\\SHAREDACCOUNT would be like this
suppose email account is tarun@abc.com then
abc\\tarun\\shared_MB

You have to also enter the password of tarun@abc.com account.

Comment: yes, this was the answer! In my case I also had to deny GSSAPI. So deny just every AUTH Methods which will be published by the exchange Server. I noticed it when i was studing the log-File from Thunderbird. Here is the whole story: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10501406&#10501406

Comment: My login always fails. Do I have to use the display-names of the user and shared mailbox or their mail addresses (with or without tld)? If Domain is "abc.com" and User is "tarun@abc.com" with name "TarunName" and shared mailbox is "shared@abc.com" with name "SharedName" what is my login string?

Comment: If you use abc/tarun as a user name to access your mail account through web then your login string will be abc/tarun/shared.

Comment: I was having trouble logging into a shared mailbox too. Apparently Exchange Shared Mailboxes have two aliases. One so-called "pre-windows 2000" with fewer characters. And the other one is the normal alias which can have more than characters than the other one. We had to use the long one in order to log in with the JavaMail API.