# Login with domain/user/account not working with imap on exchange server using javamail

Tags: exchange-server, jakarta-mail, imap, impersonation

I'm trying to connect to an exchange mailserver (not sure what version) using javamail.
I have the username and password of an account that can impersonate all other users.
I'm trying to open the store of one of the users. (password unknown)

I did find this question [How to use Javamail for accessing additional mailboxes (IMAP, Exchange 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719205/how-to-use-javamail-for-accessing-additional-mailboxes-imap-exchange-2010). It's using [domain]/[user]/[sharedaccount] as login.

The connection is made if I only use [domain]/[user], but with the name of the second account behind it [domain]/[user]/[impersonatedaccount] it won't work.
If I use the same credentials in Thunderbird it does make the connection.

**Example:**
domain: abc
known username with password: admin
mailbox to connect to: wverleur@abc.com (logs in with wverleur)
Working:
abc/admin
not working:
abc/admin/wverleur

**`credentials` contains the following:**
rootUrl: mailserver.abc.com
username: admin
password: password
domain: abc
impersonation: wverleur
getImapUsername() returns domain/username/impersonation

**My connection code:**

```
private void login() throws MessagingException {
    // connection properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    // TLS & SSL
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", credentials.getRootUrl()); // self signed certificate

    // login settings
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");


    // retrieve a session
    session = Session.getInstance(properties);

    // retrieve and open a store
    store = session.getStore("imap");


    try {
        store.connect(credentials.getRootUrl(), credentials.getImapUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
    } catch (MessagingException messagingException) {
        throw new MessagingException("Error in storeConnect: " + store.toString(),
                messagingException);
    }
}
```

**Javamail Debug shows the following:**
`DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=[rooturl], user=[domain]\[user]\[impersonate], password=<non-null>`

Am I missing something?
Is it even possible at all?

Comment: Have you tried undergoing the login process just using socat/telnet/some other network tool and going through the IMAP login process?  This is a great way to troubleshoot connection and authentication issues.

Comment: I did not. However the problem has been solved. The server required a secure connection when using impersonation, but not with a regular login (not sure why). I'll delete this question because I think it is not very useful for anybody. It's a very specific question.

Comment: Please don't delete the question.  The question of how to impersonate a user with Exchange comes up now and then and it's good to have an example showing how it works.  Provide your own answer showing how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per request of [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon) I hereby post my answer to the question:

1. I placed the required certificate in the cacerts file of Java (be sure that you know what you are doing)
2. I changed my properties to:
   *please note that they are now imap and not imaps*

   ```
   // TLS & SSL
   properties.setProperty("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
   properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "false"); // is now false
   // removed the trust for ssl

   // login settings
   properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
   properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
   properties.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.gssapi.disable", "true");

   properties.setProperty("mail.user", credentials.getImapUsername());
   properties.setProperty("mail.host", credentials.getRootUrl());
   ```

And, for me, it works.
As stated before. This is a very server specific answer and question. I hope it can help other people in their effort to connect their program to their exchange server.

---

**EDIT:**
Due to the requirement for support of other mail-servers the code changed:

```
String protocol = "mail.imap";
switch (encryption){  
    case SSL:
        protocol = protocol + "s";
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".starttls.enable", "false");
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".ssl.enable", "true");
        break;
    case TLS:
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".ssl.enable", "false");
        break;
    case NONE:
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".starttls.enable", "false");
        properties.setProperty(protocol + ".ssl.enable", "false");
        break;
}
properties.setProperty(protocol + ".auth.ntlm.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty(protocol + ".auth.plain.disable", "true");
properties.setProperty(protocol + ".auth.gssapi.disable", "true");
// other properties you want to set
```

SSL uses the `mail.imaps` and TLS and NONE use the `mail.imap`

Comment: This was it! Thank you! 
> please note that they are now imap and not imaps